# Why is my environment not taking the style I specify?

Tags: color, environments

I'm generating a `.tex` file from `.rst` using Sphinx (xelatex).

I would like to create a custom class, for which the content will be rendered in red.

The generated tex properly wraps my paragraphs in their environment (or at least that's what I understand) :

```
\begin{sphinxuseclass}{custom}
\sphinxAtStartPar
This paragraph might be rendered in a custom way.

\end{sphinxuseclass}
```

And I defined a color for the environment named `custom` in the preamble

```
\newenvironment{custom}{\color{red}}{}
```

Still, the paragraph is rendered as black (with the same font as the rest of the doc).

Where am I missing something ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2):

This was a Sphinx-related issue.

After fiddling around, and looking at [this post](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/10719#issuecomment-1200261086) it turns out that you need to specify only the part after the suffix `sphinxclass` inside the `.rst` and the **complete** name in the preamble.

So, you'll have this in the preamble

```
\newenvironment{sphinxclasscustomizedrequirement}{\color{red}}{}
```

And this in the `.rst`

```
.. container:: customizedrequirement
   
    HELLO WORLD THIS IS A TEST
```

Notice that I use `sphinxclasscustomizedrequirement` in the former and `customizedrequirement` in the latter.